# Getting error status 408 when subscribing to a Movesense device

Tags: movesense

When trying to subscribe to a measure on a Movesense device - like HR - I get a 408 error.

`OnSubscriptionError, error: 220330000122/Meas/HR, status: 408`

What does this mean? An HTTP error code 408 is a timeout error. Does this also apply here?

I'm using the `mdsflutter` Flutter plugin, an iOS phone, and an MD Movesense device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 408 is Timeout. Basically it means that the request or response never went thru. Usually this happens if there is either BLE disconnect during handling of the request (there is a couple of seconds of interval when data does not go thru but the disconnect event has not been triggered yet), or if the sensor experienses a reset while serving the request.

The possible reset can be recognized from the brief flash of the LED or getting the /System/ResetReason from the sensors DebugService (assuming it's part of the current firmware).